# How to pass multiple components to another component in react

Tags: reactjs

I've multiple react component; `component_1, component_2, component_3`

Which I want to use inside `component_4`
I also have an array_list :

```
array_list = [
    {
        data: [{}, {}],
        renderMenu: component_1
    }, {
        data: [{}, {}],
        renderMenu: component_2
    }, {
        ..etc
    }
]
```

My Component_4 is something like this:

```
import componet_1 from 'component_1'
import componet_1 from 'component_2'
import componet_1 from 'component_3'

//next I populate the item_array here
const array_list = [
    {
    data:[{},{}],
    renderMenu:component_1
    },
    {data:[{},{}],
    renderMenu:component_2
    },
    {..etc}
    ]

class component_5 extends Component{


render(){
     <component_4    {...array_list}/>

}
}
```

I'm trying to use it inside my component_4:

```
class component_4 extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

  }

  render(){
    const {array_list} = this.props
    var contentData = [];
    array_list.forEach(function(item, index, array){
      console.log(item);
      item.data.forEach(function(item1, index, array){
          console.log(item.renderComponent);
          contentData.push(<item.renderComponent {...item}/>);
      })
    });
    return(
        <div>
        <div className="ui four column centered grid">
          {contentData}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default component_4
```

Now, my question is, can I pass components as props like I'm passing them using `array_list`, I know it can be done using this.props.child. but here the need is different, I need a different component for different array_list.

Another question:
Can I render an array of components, like I've done using `contentData`.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: 1) it is up to you, how to pass components. 2) for `const {array_list} = this.props` you should  define prop `array_list={array_list}`, rather than `{...array_list}` 3) yes you can render  array of components , for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622714/dynamic-instantiation-of-child-components-by-string-name-reactjs/38627964#38627964

Answer (score 0):

One clean solution would be not to pass the component directly at all, but **only an identifier that can be used in `Component_4` to map the individual entries** to the different components.

For example:

```
import React from 'react'
import Component_1 from './Component_1'
import Component_2 from './Component_2'
import Component_3 from './Component_3'

export default const Component_4 = (props) => {
    const items = props.items.map((item) => {
        switch (item.type) {
            case '1': return <Component_1 {...item} />
            case '2': return <Component_2 {...item} />
            case '3': return <Component_3 {...item} />
            default:  return null
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="ui four column centered grid">
                {items}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

```
import React from 'react'
import Component_4 from './Component_4'

const items = [
    {
        data: [{}, {}],
        type: '1'
    }, {
        data: [{}, {}],
        type: '2'
    }, {
        ..etc
    }
]

export default const Component_5 = () => (
    <Component_4 items={items} />
)
```